# Handling trackpad zoom in WinUI 3 Canvas

Tags: c#, winui-3

Many Windows applications support two fingered touchpad gestures. You can scroll by moving two fingers horizontally or vertically, and you can zoom by changing the distance between the fingers.

I'm trying replicate this behaviour in a WinUI 3 canvas.

According to [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/touch-interactions) "The touchpad does not raise manipulation events. Instead, pointer events will be raised for touchpad input."

Listening for the `PointerWheelChanged` event handler, I'm able to detect two finger scrolls with the following code

```
private void OnPointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(myCanvas);
    var isHorizontalScroll = pointer.Properties.IsHorizontalMouseWheel;
    var scrollDelta = pointer.Properties.MouseWheelDelta;
    
    // Perform the scrolling
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

But, I'm unable to get the fingers position so I can calculate the zoom delta. Is there some lower API I can use that will give me access to the individual fingers? Or some other way to capture the zoom gesture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a little sample for you, which handles zoom using the trackpad:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" PointerWheelChanged="Canvas_PointerWheelChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Green">
    <Rectangle Width="40" Height="40" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.ZIndex="0" />
</Canvas>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Canvas_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = Microsoft.UI.Input.InputKeyboardSource.GetKeyStateForCurrentThread(Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control

    if (ctrl.HasFlag(Windows.UI.Core.CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down))
    {
        var delta = e.GetCurrentPoint(myCanvas).Properties.MouseWheelDelta;
        
        //Here you can handle your zooming    

        //My sample just resizes the rectangle
        foreach (UIElement children in myCanvas.Children)
        {
            if (children is Rectangle rect)
            {
                double newSize = rect.Height + delta;
                if (newSize < 0)
                    newSize = 0;

                rect.Height = rect.Width = newSize;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is, to check for the control-key press in the PointerWheelChanged-event, because the touchpad behaves the same like when you zoom using control + Mousewheel

Comment: Checking the Ctrl key made it work, but unfortunately it's not very smooth since it moves in 120 increments. To get the CtrlKey in WinUI 3 Desktop use GetKeyStateForCurrentThread: 

var ctrlKey = Microsoft.UI.Input.InputKeyboardSource.GetKeyStateForCurrentThread(Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control);

Comment: You can simply divide the delta to get a slower zoom, it also should be more smooth then